# Error to connecting database in Spring using properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, mybatis

I found following error in Spring.

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ${jdbc.driverClassName}
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ${jdbc.driverClassName}
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:364)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy9.insert(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:236)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:46)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:43)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy10.insertUserInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.da.thinkserver.centro.dao.impl.UserInfoDaoImpl.inserUserInfo(UserInfoDaoImpl.java:17)
    at com.da.thinkserver.centro.UserInfoTest.userInfoTest(UserInfoTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ${jdbc.driverClassName}
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ${jdbc.driverClassName}
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:150)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:354)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ${jdbc.driverClassName}
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.openConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:80)
    at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.getConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:66)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.getConnection(BaseExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:69)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:44)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:100)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:148)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ${jdbc.driverClassName}
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:631)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${jdbc.driverClassName}
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 65 more
```

Following bean xml I used to connect database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>
    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!--  
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/thinkserver" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
    -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:mapper/*.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
      <property name="basePackage" value="com.da.thinkserver.centro.dao.mapper" />
      <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

database.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/thinkserver
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=
```

Check the screenshot for directory structure.

[image]

Comment: Is the properties at the root of the classpath?

Comment: Yes, /resources/database.properties.

Comment: Your example works for me, if everything in `/resources` is at root of the classpath?

Comment: Are you using maven? and did you mean `src/main/resources`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I added screenshot.

Comment: @BhargavPanchal See my answer below. The file wasn't on the classpath.

Comment: Have you tried with hardcoded values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
      <property name="basePackage" value="com.da.thinkserver.centro.dao.mapper" />
      <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

To

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
      <property name="basePackage" value="com.da.thinkserver.centro.dao.mapper" />
</bean>
```

No need to set sqlSessionFactory.

Comment: On its own, this wouldn't of fixed anything.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you've declared `src/main/resources` as a `source folder` in Eclipse. So it won't use it in the classpath when launching your application.

Right-click the `/resources` folder and select `Build Path -> Use as source folder`.

For whatever reason, `maven` didn't do it for you.

Comment: It looks good to me. Try 2 more things. Right-click your project and `Maven -> Update Project`. Then do a clean and rebuild.

Comment: @BhargavPanchal Let's try some more. Use a command line tool, navigate to your project and run `mvn clean install`. Check the created `/target/classes` directory for your file. If it's in there, it should work. Something would be wrong with your Eclipse (close and restart). If it's not in there, we got other problems.

Comment: @BhargavPanchal If `database.properties` is in there, the problem is with Eclipse's Maven plugin.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38124/discussion-between-bhargav-panchal-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Comment: I found the problem check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Properties file is not being picked up by maven during packaging. Verify by generating war file and extract the war, and you should find jdbc.properties inside WEB-INF/classes folder. If u are not finding it then problem is wth you pom.xml.

Trying adding something like below for ur build

```
<build>
<outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.class</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/*</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered a similar problem before, then I solved it. As shown below: do not use database.properties，Write directly in the bean xml.

[image: show in the image]

Answer (score -2):

Off the top of my head: you need to tell Spring about database.properties file, right? How are you doing it? Something like this?

`<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:database.properties"/>`

Comment: `context:property-placeholder` does that.